# Convert SQL Into Datamapper request

Tags: sql, ruby, datamapper

Is it possible to convert this SQL Query Request into Datamapper?

```
SELECT twitchtv 
FROM twitchtvsts 
WHERE twitchtvsts.user_id = thisisavaraible


get '/watch/:id' do |id|
    erb :mystream 
    result = repository(:default).adapter
                             .select(
                                     'SELECT twitchtv 
                                      FROM twitchtvsts 
                                      WHERE twitchtvsts.user_id = id'
                                    )
    puts result
```

Comment: Is it something like this ?? var = Twitchtvst.get(:twitchtv => )

Comment: Are you using `ActiveRecord` ?

Comment: Adbo look at my last question..thank you very much but I still have a bit of problem. Thing is that it gets as #<Twitchtvst:0x007fb48b4d5a98> now.How do I convert this into string like the thing I have insert into SQL? Do you copy what I'm saying? :)

Comment: no I'm not using ActiveRecord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write as below :

```
Twitchtvsts.all( :fields => [:twitchtv ], 
                 :conditions => { :user_id => id_var }           
               )
```

Read this [`Projecting only specific properties`](http://datamapper.org/docs/find.html) .

Comment: It seems like this lists all my entries but I only want them to list one. How do I get the variable?? {id}? here is my output on terminal when I have id as variable SELECT twitchtv 
                                      FROM twitchtvsts 
                                      WHERE twitchtvsts.user_id = id
gsl
day9tv
dendi
dotacinema

Comment: get '/watch/:id' do |id|
    erb :mystream 
    result = repository(:default).adapter
                             .select(
                                     'SELECT twitchtv 
                                      FROM twitchtvsts 
                                      WHERE twitchtvsts.user_id = id'
                                    )
    puts result

Comment: @user2945872 what is your problem now /

Comment: how do I get a varible into the String # dosents wwork

Comment: thank you very much but I still have a bit of problem. Thing is that it gets as #<Twitchtvst:0x007fb48b4d5a98> now.How do I convert this into string like the thing I have insert into SQL? Do you copy what I'm saying? :)